# Verb for "make [object] available"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I have a feeling that I am overlooking a common word, but which word should I use to say that "I will *make myself available* for you tomorrow" or convey similar thoughts?

The word is **not** "avail" (which has a meaning similar to "benefit"; "avail of" means "to make use of"). So, I would like the word that describes the process of putting an object into a state where someone may avail himself of that object.

Comment: Why could you not say "I will avail myself tomorrow for you"?

Comment: @tylerharms: Because that would mean "I will use myself beneficially tomorrow for you", which may not mean the same thing, depending on context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only think of the word **enable** to convey the idea of an object's change of state to readiness for use.

Comment: This doesn't feel like a clear winner, but after a year of pondering this question on and off, I couldn't think of a better word.

Answer (score 2):

What about "I'll be at your disposal tomorrow?"

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/disposal

Answer (score 0):

***to grant?***

Definitions:
1a : to consent to carry out for a person : allow fulfillment of
grant a request
b : to permit as a right, privilege, or favor
luggage allowances granted to passengers

Comment: Please add the source and links for your definitions.

Comment: And a sentence with that word in context.